# YouTube Data API: OAuth Authentication for services using V3 without user intervention

Tags: java, api, authentication, youtube, youtube-api

I'm implementing a service that automatically uploads videos to a YouTube channel once they are uploaded on a different server.

When I first started I was using ClientLogin authentication and [YouTube API v2.0 – Direct Uploading](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading) and everything worked perfectly. However, since ClientLogin is deprecated, I'm trying to update to use v3.0.

I checked [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) and it assumes that the file is stored locally, which in my case is not, and this service will not be running on my local machine, and I'm not able to get the access token for OAuth 2.0.

Can anybody provide guidance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do so by getting a refresh token from [OAuth2 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and setting it in your youtube object.

[Here it explains a little more.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#standalone)

[And a step by step video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJjQPaPAfWM)

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. I got it working and got a refresh token that I will just hardcode to get new access tokens