# Google Youtube Data API: Private videos with API key

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

So we have some training videos on youtube that are private. We want people that log into our system to be able to access those videos, but I don't want them to have to login with oauth.

I want our app to do the authentication to OUR account and when our app uses the api, I want it to return private videos. (I'm fine with using the API key and limiting the referral)

I've played around with the api, but the api key does not return private videos.

It always return an empty array of items.

How can I do this?

Comment: Greetings well can you provide the link to such documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to OAuth to your own account for that. Though you can do this without authenticating all the time. [YouTube Data API: OAuth Authentication for services using V3 without user intervention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057358/youtube-data-api-oauth-authentication-for-services-using-v3-without-user-interv/21100089#21100089)

Comment: But oAuth does not meet my needs. oAuth requires some user interaction for authentication. I want my application to authenticate itself. From what I've read youtube does not support service apps which blows. Any other suggestions.

Comment: In the link above, it tells you how to do oauth without user intervention!!!! Service accounts are not supported in YT API yet.

Comment: Calm down. and NO it does not. you still have to authenticate with a human being. There is no way around that.  Also, as with all the other SO answers, you cannot do what I'm asking.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? i have the same problem

Comment: I created access token, Please tell me how I use to play private video in android

Comment: Did found a way?

Comment: @SenicaGonzalez - Ibrahim's answer is exactly what you are asking for, and is widely used as the only work-around for the lack of service account support for OAuth2-protected API endpoints.