# Youtube API - do i need youtube sign in password to upload a video to channel?

Tags: php, youtube-api

I've try to make browser-based video upload in youtube. And i've got this code from the internet. From this tutorial.

http://www.rd2inc.com/blog/2012/08/youtube-browser-based-uploader-with-php/

Now the question is: why do i need youtube password, when i use developer key?

$youtube_email = ""; // Change this to your youtube sign in email.
    $youtube_password = ""; // Change this to your youtube sign in password.
    // Developer key: Get your key here: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/.
    $key = "";

```
$source = ''; // A short string that identifies your application for logging purposes.
$postdata = "Email=".$youtube_email."&Passwd=".$youtube_password."&service=youtube&source=" . $source;
$curl = curl_init( "https://www.google.com/youtube/accounts/ClientLogin" );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1 );
$response = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );

list( $auth, $youtubeuser ) = explode( "\n", $response );
list( $authlabel, $authvalue ) = array_map( "trim", explode( "=", $auth ) );
list( $youtubeuserlabel, $youtubeuservalue ) = array_map( "trim", explode( "=", $youtubeuser ) );

$youtube_video_title = $video_title; // This is the uploading video title.
$youtube_video_description = $video_description; // This is the uploading video description.   
$youtube_video_keywords = "demo"; // This is the uploading video keywords.
$youtube_video_category = "Tech";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer. You have to go through OAuth2, you shouldn't put your email or pass in your code.

In OAuth2 user will have to use it.

If you are doing it for server, just for your account, you can also check this: [YouTube Data API: OAuth Authentication for services using V3 without user intervention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057358/youtube-data-api-oauth-authentication-for-services-using-v3-without-user-interv/21100089#21100089)