# GET Channel ID using Youtube API v3 with Service Account

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

Good Day, I Try to Get Channel ID using service account, because I´m using it on other scopes on my project. But when I do request process its give me the service account information. i´m using php btw

Many thanks in advance and any help will be appreciated.

p.d. i´m replace real account info for dummy text.

[image: Channel id on the tab and results image]

And of Course the code :

```
$credentials_file = $this->key_dir . $this->key_file['title'];

    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig($credentials_file);
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');

    $client->setApplicationName("Youtube Analytics");
    $client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();

    $token = $client->getAccessToken();
    $accessToken = $token['access_token'];
    if (!empty($accessToken)) {

    $service = new \Google_Service_YouTube($client);

    $data = $service->channels->listChannels('id,snippet', array('mine' => 'true'));

    echo "id: " . $data->items[0]->id . "<br>";
    echo "Kind: " . $data->items[0]->kind . "<br>";
    echo "Snippet -> title : " . $data->items[0]->snippet['title'] . "<br>";

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, Youtube API doesn't support Service Account Flow. As described in the [document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) :

> The service account flow supports server-to-server interactions that do not access user information. However, the YouTube Data API does not support this flow. Since there is no way to link a Service Account to a YouTube account, attempts to authorize requests with this flow will generate a **`NoLinkedYouTubeAccount`** error.

Also in the [Youtube v3 Google Service Account Access](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5370) issue, "There are no plans to add support for Service Account authorization to YouTube Data API v3 calls." As stated in the related SO question [#21890982](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21892335/5995040) and [#21057358](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100089/5995040) : you'll need your own account for that and you can create an authentication for services using V3 without user intervention.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many Thanks, @Mr.Rebot that´s correct and cristal clear.