# you tube API view private video in my website

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I want to view youtube's private video in my website.
Normally, youtube allow us to embedded video to our website if we upload video as public or unlisted. But if we do like this when someone know our link they can share it to other one.
For my wanted I don't want they share my video I allow them watch in my website only.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Ibrahim Ulukaya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1973552/ibrahim-ulukaya) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890982/google-youtube-data-api-private-videos-with-api-key),

> You need to OAuth to your own account for that. Though you can do this
>   without authenticating all the time. [YouTube Data API: OAuth Authentication for services using V3 without user intervention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057358/youtube-data-api-oauth-authentication-for-services-using-v3-without-user-interv/21100089#21100089)

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by Youtube API yet. What you can do is upload your videos on your website and create different passwords for different users like membership areas. Check [this site](https://www.websitetooltester.com/en/blog/create-a-password-protected-website/) for additional insight.