# How to embed and play private videos using YouTube-API-V3

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have an application which uploads videos on YouTube with privacy status as private, but when I try to play them using iFrame (YouTube Player), it states the video is private. When I sign in to YouTube in another tab then it's playing.

Is there any way to play private videos while the authorization/sign in will be handled in the backend using YouTube-API?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890982/google-youtube-data-api-private-videos-with-api-key).

You need to an OAuth to your account for that. You have the capacity to do this without authenticating all the time. [YouTube Data API: OAuth Authentication for services using V3 without user intervention.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057358/youtube-data-api-oauth-authentication-for-services-using-v3-without-user-interv/21100089#21100089)

Comment: I created access token, Please tell me how I use to play private video in android.