# How set access token to YouTubeView?

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

I am playing videos in my android app from my YouTube account using YouTube Data API v3.

Initially, I was only playing public videos and using YouTubeView for that.

But I also want to play private videos and for that, I generated an access token, But I don't know how I can use that for play my private video.

So, Please tell me how I can use my access token.

I am not providing any additional parameters, I am just initializing my YouTubeView like this,

```
youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I not tried anything because I didn't, how to use the access token. I edited my question and added how I am initializing my YouTubeView.

Comment: private video as in "only you have access to it on youtube" right? and not one from your phone for example.

Comment: But in this question it told that we can play private video after getting access token https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757880/how-to-embed-and-play-private-videos-using-youtube-api-v3